# Babel transpiler global from CLI

Tags: babeljs

I'm trying to get to grips with the babel transpiler. It's docs start by telling you how to install it globally, and then, shortly thereafter tells you you should never do this, and never explains how to *run* it that way. Well, I believe I wish to run it that way (because the presence of the node_modules directory, or possibly the .babelrc file, cripples brackets, which is the editor I'm currently needing to use).

I can run babel from the global installation easily enough, but it doesn't do anything. The only way I've succeeded in getting it to do any actual translation has been using the local invocation with the .babelrc file, which of course kills my editor (and yes, I actually do have to use that, and I'm not creating a node-based project in any other way, just plain ES6).

Is there some way to use the command line to provide the information that the .babelrc file specifies (and thereby have something other than simply file copying)? Or some other way to get babel to do what I need without physical presence in my source tree?

Comment: I've worked out that if I create a "working directory" for Babel, then I can hack my way around the problem by soft linking my real work directory undeneath this, so that brackets doesn't see the node_modules etc. stuff. So, I guess I've fixed this, but I can't help wondering if there's a better way?

Comment: What in brackets fails? Seems like figuring out how to fix that would be the import important question to answer.

Comment: Well, I have no clue. It spins a CPU up to 100%, and the UI is essentially unresponsive. Sometimes it manages to paint one rendering of its window. Many times, the window is simply white.

Comment: Sounds more like that is the issue you should fix: https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/11733 Not having a local `node_modules` is definitely something to be avoided.